# Property 'ChildBrowser' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript

I migrate my hybrid mobile project from JS to Typescript and I got error in console during compilation

> error TS2339: Property 'ChildBrowser' does not exist on type '{ pushNotification: PushNotification; }

this is my code

```
window.plugins.ChildBrowser.showWebPage(text,
                { showLocationBar: true, showAddress: true, showNavigationBar: true });
        }
```

but WebStorm doesn't highlight any error in this row.

I created my own d.ts file, which contains this code (bellow) and I include this file to my ts file

```
interface Window {
    plugins: Plugins; 
    pushNotification: PushNotification;
}

interface PushNotification{
    emailComposer: EmailComposer;
    ChildBrowser: ChildBrowser;
    socialsharing: Socialsharing;
}

interface ChildBrowser{
    showWebPage: any;
}

interface Socialsharing {

}
interface EmailComposer{
    showEmailComposerWithCallback(fu: any, ... fu2: any[]): any;
}

interface Plugins {
    emailComposer: EmailComposer;
    ChildBrowser: ChildBrowser;
    socialsharing: Socialsharing;
    
}
```

unfortunately I still get this message

> 8 non-emit-preventing type warnings
> Type errors only.
>
> TypeScript compilation complete: 3.98s for 23 TypeScript files.
>
> Done, without errors.
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Please, can anybody help me?
Regards

Comment: It looks like your script is compiling, so what's the problem?

Comment: Yes, my code is compiled, but I would like to suppress all warning messages in console.

Comment: Ok, then tell us what the warnings are, since you seem to have resolved the first error.

Comment: Its same as my first written error-warning.This is incomplete 
extract 
<pre>
 error TS2428: All declarations of 'JQueryPromise' must have identical type parameters.
 error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'plugins' must be of type '{ pushNotification: PushNotification; }', but here has type 'PushNotification'.
 error TS2339: Property 'emailComposer' does not exist on type '{ pushNotification: PushNotification; }'.
 error TS2339: Property 'socialsharing' does not exist on type '{ pushNotification: PushNotification; }'.</pre>